# Xcode adding localisation strings file for unsupported languages(like indian language sindhi)?

Tags: ios, localization

I had given support for multiple languages inside my iOS project using string localization. I had added supported language **Localizable.strings** files from project setting. But how to do same thing for language which is not available in Xcode list(like indian language sindhi).Please suggest for same.

Comment: So iOS doesn't support Sindhi?

Comment: @trojanfoe,as per my knowledge , not supported hence not in list. You can check supported language list here https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273.